# Bash script - ERROR 1 (HY000) - save tables from database

Tags: mysql, database, bash, shell, debian

I have to repare some scripts, which stopped to work. 
There is the `export.sh` script, which should copy and save tables from database:

```
DATAPUMP="/tmp/DataPump/"       # Where tables have to be saved and where the old tables are saved 
TABLELIST="MyShop5TableList"    # Where names of tables are saved
DBSOURCE="somedb"               # DB name
EXPORTDIR="../export/"          # Where copies of tables have to be saved

rm ${DATAPUMP}*.export

for table in `cat ${TABLELIST}`; do
mysql -D ${DBSOURCE} -pPassword << EOF
select * into outfile "${DATAPUMP}${table}.export" from ${table};
EOF
done

cp ${DATAPUMP}* ${EXPORTDIR}
```

When I try to run the script export.sh, there is an error message:

```
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/DataPump/*.export': No such file or directory.
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can’t create/write to file "/tmp/DataPump/goods.export"(Errcode: 2)
# *and the same ERROR 1 for all other tables*
```

So I tryed to change the DATAPUMP directory to `DATAPUMP="tmp/DataPump/"` (just without the "/" at the beginning). The files was removed, but the ERROR 1 message still appears (now little bit different):

```
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can’t create/write to file "var/lib/mysql/tmp/DataPump/goods.export"(Errcode: 2)
# *and the same ERROR 1 for all other tables*
```

The path to files is changed. I'm new to bash script and I really don't know what is wrong.
PS: The script was working for a long time... We don't know what happened

Comment: The script should have the rights to write into the DATAPUMP directory. Therefore you should look into /etc/crontab (or wherever it is executed) to see if it is executed as user root or another. Then look into /tmp if there is the DataPump directory and if the rights are still correct. Then undo your change and run the script as it is defined in your crontab. Maybe just someone deleted the DataPump directory in /tmp.

Comment: I execute the script manually, there is no crontab. And give the permissions like [here](http://superuser.com/questions/19318/how-can-i-give-write-access-of-a-folder-to-all-users-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I would bet it is permissions. Try to chown the directories which you are writing files in. Then run the script.

```
chown -R foo /some/path
```

This changes the ownsership to foo from root for the path directory at /some/path